# How to get character input at runtime from a procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to convert Canadian dollars to other currencies with some convention.
I am creating a procedure and taking the input of amount in number and char to convert the currency at runtime but the procedure is getting created with some errors.

Here is the code.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE conversion(p_cad_dollars IN NUMBER, p_new_currency IN VARCHAR2(10)) AS
v_result NUMBER;
v_new_currency VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    if p_new_currency = 'E' THEN
        v_result := p_cad_dollars * 1.50;
        v_new_currency := 'EURO';
    ELSIF p_new_currency = 'Y' THEN
        v_result := p_cad_dollars * 100;
        v_new_currency := 'YEN';
    ELSIF p_new_currency = 'V' THEN
        v_result := p_cad_dollars * 10000;
        v_new_currency := 'Viet Nam DONG';
    ELSIF p_new_currency = 'Z' THEN
        v_result := p_cad_dollars * 1000000;
        v_new_currency := 'Endora ZIP';
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('For "' || p_cad_dollars || '" dollars Canadian, you will have "' || v_result || '" ' || v_new_currency);
END;
/
```

I am getting this error after compilation
[image: error for the code]

How can I get rid of this error and get the desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p_new_currency` parameter is declared wrong. Drop the `(10)`. Procedure parameters cannot state a size. Refer to Oracle documentation, specifically [PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/index.html)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE conversion(p_cad_dollars  IN NUMBER,
                                       p_new_currency IN VARCHAR2) AS
  v_result       NUMBER;
  v_new_currency VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  if p_new_currency = 'E' THEN
    v_result       := p_cad_dollars * 1.50;
    v_new_currency := 'EURO';
  ELSIF p_new_currency = 'Y' THEN
    v_result       := p_cad_dollars * 100;
    v_new_currency := 'YEN';
  ELSIF p_new_currency = 'V' THEN
    v_result       := p_cad_dollars * 10000;
    v_new_currency := 'Viet Nam DONG';
  ELSIF p_new_currency = 'Z' THEN
    v_result       := p_cad_dollars * 1000000;
    v_new_currency := 'Endora ZIP';
  END IF;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('For "' || p_cad_dollars ||
                       '" dollars Canadian, you will have "' || v_result || '" ' ||
                       v_new_currency);
END;
/
```